# Is there a simple way to convert MP3 to WAV in vb2005?

Tags: vb.net, audio

Is there a simple way to convert MP3 to WAV in vb2005?

what i would like to do is play MP3 files in vb2005 but first they need to be converted to a byte(memory) wave string before they can be played internally by the program unless someone else built a class or module for this already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than writing code to convert the files, you can use the DirectX libraries to play the MP3 files.

Read [this discussion](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/136871-Mp3-Playback-in-VBNet/) and take a look at [this example usage](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives3/archive508.html).

Answer (score 2):

This has been done by quite a few people, most using c# but since that can be trivially consumed by your VB.net code this should be no problem.
Many use the managed Direct Sound apis here's [how to use them to play and mp3](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/DirectX/Csharp/Series2/tut17.php)

This question has been [asked](http://channel9.msdn.com/forums/TechOff/136871-Mp3-Playback-in-VBNet/) and answered well over on channel9 so there's no point rehashing it but pointing out how easy it is to do it is worth while:

```
AudioVideoPlayback.Audio mp3 = new AudioVideoPlayback.Audio("mySong.mp3");
mp3.Play();
```

if you want a simple no dependency dll to do it look at [MP3Sharp](http://www.robburke.net/mle/mp3sharp/)